# ASP.NET Core 2.2, input formatters for XML

Tags: xml, rest, asp.net-core-2.2, inputformatter

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 and trying to allow additional content-type value for XML. So I configured in `Startup.cs` like this.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

In fact, I ended up getting `415 Unsupported Media Type` status in postman. Has anyone succeeded with adding XML content-type value?

AuthorsController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAuthor([FromBody] AuthorForCreationDto author)
    {
        ...
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `RespectBrowserAcceptHeader` to true to allow content negotiation.

```
// Add XML Content Negotiation
config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;


services.AddMvc(options => {
    //Enable this to allow content negotiation.
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;

    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I still see `415` response. Is `options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;` tested in 2.2?

Comment: so  services.AddMvc(options => { options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options)); }); is used for converting null or empty value to type 'enum' or is there any other way to convert null or empty value to type enum??